# Indexing Service Problem

Tags: indexing-service

I've got an HTML file which I'm having a problem with through Index Server. Here is the text in question.

```
   (B)   $10,800 per linear mile for 


   (C)   $40,000 per linear mile for any
```

My problem is with the dollar amounts.

- If I search for 800, it finds the document
- If I search for $10, it finds the document
- If I search for $40, it finds the document
- If I search for $10,800, 10,800, $40,000 or 40,000 it will not find the document, regardless of if I surround the text with double quotes.

I thought perhaps it was the comma, but I can find other documents in the indexing server repository with the 40,000 and it will find it.  I've deleted the catalog and re-indexed the entire data structure, with no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out (after about two days):

There were a series of non-breaking spaces (& nbsp;) right before the text in question. I replaced the last one with a physical space and re-indexed it - I guess the indexing service isn't smart enough to ignore those or to treat them as  A SPACE!